# Can I replace this thermal relay with a conventional electromechanical relay?

Tags: relay

I have an old Thermador range with an electric oven.

The relay for the oven is activated by heating some sort of metallic(?) strip which expands and closes the hi-voltage contacts. This deviceis a "thermally operated relay" - it is not a thermostat or "simmerstat". The thermal time constant introduces a delay of several seconds (which is generally of no consequence when baking a cake).

The relay is located on the frame under the oven.
There is a separate temperature sensor and a temperature control that feed a control module. The control module cycles the heater element on and off (as one would expect) using this relay. The bimetallic strip has nothing to do with the temperature control. it is used instead of a magnetic coil to open/close the armature/contacts (which is strange and is what I'm wondering about).

Aside from just being curious about why it works this way, the reason I ask is that a replacement relay is no longer available and there is probably a limit to how many times I can resurface the contacts which burn out periodically.

If I replaced it with a 'normal' hi-current relay, would there be a problem?

[image]

Comment: Where is this relay located in the oven, both electrically (what does it turn on and what turns it on) and physically (is it in the control box or inside the oven itself)?

Comment: Delay between what and what?

Comment: The bimetallic strip is a vital part of the temperature control for the oven - a normal relay will not provide the temperature control, and there won't be anything to control the normal relay anyway.

Comment: Is there really a relay with a coil and armature driving contacts or are you just describing a bi-metallic thermostat (with no coil and armature)? Can you post a photo?

Comment: its located on the frame under the oven. There is a separate temperature sensor and (obviously) a temperature control that feed a control module. The control module cycles the heater element on and off (as one would expect) using this relay. The bimetallic strip has nothing to do with the temperature control. it is used instead of a magnetic coil to open/close the armature/contacts (which is strange and is what I'm wondering about). There is a not very helpful photo here (wish i could post a photo) https://www.ebay.com/itm/255331156631?hash=item3b72ec4297:g:a1cAAOSwr85h4UkL

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Bimetalic strip is a specially constructed piece of hardware which provides an on-off temperature control. Probably it is *not* a bimetallic strip what you are talking about, or some kind of safety shut-off controller which will turn your oven off if the other temperature control is failing..

Comment: OTOH, your link led me to the [hot wire relay](http://www.tpub.com/utilities/156.htm) thing.

Comment: actually you are right - i misspoke - its not bimetallic. its a low voltage coil wrapped around something. It heats that something up which expands slightly and leverages the armature to close. Its somewhat analogous to a hot water zone control valve in that way. I have one sitting in front of me and a good photo of it if only i could insert it here...

Comment: Eugene, yes your link is to a similar device. Good find...

Comment: thanks for the help - I just posted a photo above. the cover is removed. the connector lugs for the high and low voltage are located underneath.

Comment: It "seems very likely" that replacing this unit with a solid state relay with suitable Voperate and load V & I ratings would wok well. You could CARFUULY measure the control voltage when on and when off. May be AC or DC but seems liable to be low voltage DC. Take due care. Report back if needed.

Comment: Russell - thanks. Good input. Yes I will take care if I ever do the replacement. But the curious engineer in me would still love to know why Thermador designed it this way...

Comment: @AlChisholm I'd guess it was a cheaper solution. As a bonus it is unusual so they can charge premium prices for replacement :-). I may be wrong :-)

Comment: **SEPTEMBER 3RD:**  Closed and reopened - I have edited the question to remove the two different close vote objections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification in your question and the comments below your question. I have never seen one of these although it is similar to a hob ring controller but without any setpoint adjustment.

[image]

I can think of two reasons for this device:

1. The main thermostat is not rated for the oven current. A relay is required.
2. The thermostat doesn't have enough hysteresis to prevent chatter or excessive switching frequency. Adding the thermal time delay of, say, 5 s means that one switching cycle would be 10 s giving a maximum switching frequency of six times per minute. I would suspect that the delay introduces a little more temperature swing above and below the thermostat's setpoint and that will further reduce the number of cycles per minute.

The bimetallic strip will toggle the armature abruptly giving rapid contact opening and closing to minimise arcing and contact wear.

---

> So if I replaced it with a 'normal' hi-current relay, would there be a problem?

There might or might not! If the switching frequency is increased you may stress the thermostat contacts. A mains relay or contactor's pull-in current will be high until the armature closes, causing the inductance to increase dramatically and the AC current to reduce. This switch-on surge might be the problem. (The existing relay coil would have negligible inductance.)

Comment: thanks - i was also thinking it might be hysteresis (although you would think that could have been incorporated into the control module). Anyway if/when it gets to the point where I cant refurbish it any more, a regular relay is probably worth a try. (I have searched briefly for replacement parts for other stove brands that I could perhaps adapt but no luck so far...). And its working for now...